# Appcelerator Titanium - XML parse in Android not working

Tags: android, ios, xml, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

As the title says, in Android I can not get the XML parse to work. In iOS works correctly.
This code is from Appcelerator and this is the link to the documentation page: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Working_with_XML_Data

```
    var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor:'#fff'
    });

    var data = [];
    var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({backgroundColor:"red"});
    win.add(table);

    var url="http://apod.nasa.gov/apod.rss"; //  rss feed url
    var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

    xhr.onload = function() {
        // Data is returned from the blog, start parsing
        var doc = this.responseXML.documentElement;

        // begin looping through blog posts
        var items = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
            data.push({
                title: items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).text
            });
        }
        table.data = data;
    };
    xhr.onerror = function(e) {
        // should do something more robust
        alert('Network error '+e.error);
    };

    xhr.open('GET',url);
    xhr.send();

    win.open();
```

The result is different as you can see in this image
[IOS and Android example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x39z8.png)

I'm using Titanium SDK 6.1.0.GA

Has the same happened to anyone else yet?

Thank you

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console when you run the android app?

Comment: @AdamPaxton no, i'm not getting any errors in the console.
I also test it with diferents android API's and it's the same result...

Comment: Did you try using a previous version of Titanium SDK? If so - which one and was the result the same?

Comment: @nebu Just tried with titanium sdk 5.2.0.GA and it returns the error:

    Message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null

Can someone test the code above and see if it works? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `text` with [`textContent`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.XML.Node-property-textContent):

```
    data.push({
        title: items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).textContent
    });
```

Comment: It had been replaced on both platforms some time ago, but apparently it wasn't completely removed from iOS https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-7967